# Why Wordpress CMS uses an array in wp_options instead of a field for Sticky posts?

Tags: sticky-post

In WordPress we can pin (sticky) a post.
Wordpress uses an option in `wp_options` table named 'sticky_posts' with an array list of sticky posts!

As a normal condition WordPress should add a field named 'sticky' in `wp_posts` table.

My question is why does WordPress use this way and what are Pros and Cons of this method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sticky posts are a feature of the home page, not of the post. The post has no reason to "know" it is sticky. The home page OTOH do not have any formal form of storage and therefor traditionally options related to it are stored in the options table

Comment: is there any performance benefits in this method?

Comment: @RaminFirooz compared to what?

Comment: using a 'sticky' field in wp_posts table

Comment: Well, when someone will write the code that does it like you say we will be able to compare, no? Why don't you just ask the question you actually want to ask instead of using a proxy? This feature was done like that because it was done like that, not every small piece of code is analyzed 10 times to be "best" in something.